# Logistic regression plot gives a linear regression line instead of a S-shaped curve

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, logistic-regression, glm

I am trying to plot the results from this logistic regression model in ggplot2:

```r
trees_imd_urb = glmer(trees ~ imd_score + age + gender + ethnicity + 
    education + occupation + urban_grow + urban_rural + (1|p_id), 
     family=binomial(link="logit"), 
    control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa",optCtrl=list(maxfun=2e5)),
    data = um_sub)
```

I then used this code in `ggplot2`:

```r
log_plot_trees_imd <- ggplot(um_sub, aes(x=imd_score, y=as.numeric(trees)-1))+
  geom_jitter(width=0, height = 0.05)+
  geom_smooth(method="glm", method.args=list(family=binomial))+
  labs(x="IMD scores", y="Probability of Seeing Trees")
```

[image: The plot produced by the code above]

As you can see the regression line is linear and not S-shaped, and I am not sure why..
I have changed my outcome variable to a numerical 1/0 variable, and have specified the "glm" method in the geom_smooth function.
My predictor variable is a score of socioeconomic deprivation going from 0 to 80.

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: @ZheyuanLi
Oh thank you! I've extended it (from -300 to 300) and I can now see the S-Curve. However: - My x predictor variable is a pre-defined objective measure ranging fro 0 to 80, and the data doesn't go beyond that range, it then doesn't make sense to display the results with an extended x axis? 
- + extending it makes the observation points unreadable as they get (even more) overcrowded, and means the plot is not informative 

Would you recommend staying with the initial range even if the S-shaped curve is not displayed? Or do you have any other suggestions? 
Appreciate it thank you!